# Markov Chain: Prove Absorption Probabilities Matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I was curious about the proof for the absorption probability matrix of a Markov chain.  See Scan below where I underlined in red the part that is confusing me.

[image: ABSORB PROB]

[image: ABSORB PROB 2]

Answer (score 1):

It holds that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n = j (\in A) | X_0 = i) =
\begin{cases}
1 \quad & i = j \\
0 \quad & i \in A, i \neq j \\
u_{ij} \quad & i = m+1,\dots,N \enspace (i \in B)
\end{cases}
$$
Inserting this gives:
\begin{align*}
u_{kj} &= \sum_{i = 1}^N p_{ki}\mathbb{P}(X_n = j \in A | X_0 = i) \\
&= \sum_{i \in A, i \neq j} p_{ki}\mathbb{P}(X_n = j \in A | X_0 = i)
+ p_{kj} + \sum_{i \in B} p_{ki}\mathbb{P}(X_n = j \in A | X_0 = i) \\
&= p_{kj} + \sum_{i \in B} p_{ki}u_{ij}
\end{align*}